# Why do I need lib64 on my 32 bit machine?

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, libraries, shared-library

I am trying to install Oracle on my 32-bit machine that runs Ubuntu 10.4. I am following [install Oracle on Ubuntu](http://www.pythian.com/news/13291/installing-oracle-11gr2-enterprise-edition-on-ubuntu-10-04-lucid-lynx/) tutorial. At the very first step there is a requirement to manually install library libstdc++5. Author does 2 steps:

1. download libstdc++5_3.3.6-17ubuntu1_amd64.deb from [here](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gcc-3.3/)
2. download ia32-libs_2.7ubuntu6.1_amd64.deb from [here](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/i/ia32-libs/)

As you may have probably noticed these 2 files contain an "_amd64" postfix, which pointed me out that author is using 64-bit amd processor. Each of these files author copied to /usr/lib64 and /usr/lib32 folders correspondingly and simply make soft links libstdc++.so.5 in both folders.

Since I am running 32-bit machine I have simply downloaded those 2 files without "_amd64" postfix.

Unexpectedly for me I have also found 2 lib folders in my /usr folder: /usr/lib64 and /usr/lib.

So here is my problem: I do not understand which files and where do I have to copy:

1) Do I have to make the same steps as the author has done, i.e. download files with "_amd64" postfixes and place them in my /usr/lib64 and /usr/lib folders?

2) Or do I have to use libraries without "_amd64" postfix?

And one more question: why do I have /usr/lib64 at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is partial and consists of 3 parts

Part 1. Regarding machines with AMD64 processors

What does the author of the tutorial do is:

1. He uses native libstdc++5_3.3.6-17ubuntu1_amd64.deb library for his machine with AMD64 processor
2. And additionally ia32-libs_2.7ubuntu6.1_amd64.deb that, as I may suppose, *emulates* library for IA-32 architecture and is used for AMD64 processors

Why does he make second step is not clear. Any comments are highly appreciated.

Part 2. Regarding machines with intel 32-bit processors (i386/i686)

*Most probably* in case of intel 32-bit machines and Ubuntu 10.4 installed on it the only one library (libstdc++5_3.3.6-20~lucid1_i386.deb, *note at the moment of writing the version is higher*) is necessary and it has to be placed in /usr/lib directory

Part 3. Why there is lib64 on 32-bit machine is still not clear, any comments are highly appreciated.

Comment: it seems that tutorial is actually for amd64 arch as with ia32-libs is only for amd64 arch to be able to use i386 libraries/runnables. In your place i would install newer libstdc++ and try to run appropriate Oracle installation for i386 arch. On the other hand i should not that I see no advantage to use i386 linux at the time of writing.

Comment: The only advantage that will remain for quite a while is "I have a perfectly working 32-bit processor and no willingness to upgrade it"